# How to refactor this code so that it conforms to Open-Close principle?

Tags: c#, open-closed-principle

[The question is actually derived from this link.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8797/how-to-make-sure-that-this-code-conforms-to-open-close-principle)

Suppose I have a problem like this:

---

A book-shop buys and sells two types of books:
(1) Non-technical {Title, Author, Price}
(2) Technical {Title, Author, Price, CD}

Also, customer gets a CD when he buys a Technical book. A CD object is defined as, CD {Title, Price}.

A Non-technical book’s price will be only the price of the book. A Technical book’s price will be the sum of the price of the book and the CD.

Create a C# program to show the following info:

```
Total number of book Bought & Price: XXX & XXX.XX
Total number of book Sold & Price: XXX & XXX.XX
Total Technical Book Sold & Price: XXX & XXX.XX
Total Non-technical Book sold & Price: XXX & XXX.XX
```

---

```
abstract class Publication
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}

class CD : Publication
{
}

abstract class Book : Publication
{
    public virtual string Author { get; set; }
}

class TechnicalBook : Book
{
    public CD Cd { get; set; }
    public override double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return (base.Price + Cd.Price);
        }
    }
}

class NonTechnicalbook : Book
{
}

class Shop
{
    private IDictionary<string, Book> boughtDictionary;
    private IDictionary<string, Book> soldDictionary;

    public Shop()
    {
        boughtDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
        soldDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
    }

    public virtual void Buy(Book item)
    {
        boughtDictionary.Add(item.Title, item);
    }

    public virtual void Sell(string title)
    {
        Book book = boughtDictionary[title];
        boughtDictionary.Remove(book.Title);
        soldDictionary.Add(book.Title, book);
    }

    public virtual int GetBoughtBookCount()
    {
        return boughtDictionary.Count;
    }

    public virtual double GetBoughtBookPrice()
    {
        double price = 0.0;

        foreach (string title in boughtDictionary.Keys)
        {
            price = price + boughtDictionary[title].Price;
        }
    }

    public virtual int GetSoldBookCount()
    {
        return boughtDictionary.Count;
    }

    public virtual double GetSoldBookPrice()
    {
        double price = 0.0;

        foreach (string title in soldDictionary.Keys)
        {
            price = price + soldDictionary[title].Price;
        }
    }

    public virtual double GetTotalBookCount()
    {
        return this.GetBoughtBookCount() + this.GetSoldBookCount();
    }

    public virtual double GetTotalBookPrice()
    {
        return this.GetBoughtBookPrice() + this.GetSoldBookPrice();
    }

    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of books Bought & Price: ", this.GetTotalBookCount() + " & " + this.GetTotalBookPrice());
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of books Sold & Price: ", this.GetSoldBookCount() + " & " + this.GetSoldBookPrice());
    }
}
```

How to show the prices of Technical and Non-technical books while keeping the Open-Closed Principle?

Deriving Shop-class doesn't make any sense.

If I code like the following:

```
 if(book is TechnicalBook) {
    // ...
 } else if(book is NonTechnicalBook) {
    // ...
 }
```

I don't think it keeps OCP.

Then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a method

```
getTotal(Option op)
```

where `Option` is a delagte that takes a book and returns true if it meets your criteria in your case if book is TechnicalBook or NonTechnicalBook.

the `getTotal` Method would go over all books summing only those that Option delegate returns true.
and returning the sum.

hope this is what you meant.